# Is there GtkSharp for .Net framework 3.5?

Tags: mono, gtk#

The current and stable GtkSharp releases target .Net FW 4.0, and I am looking for a version which would target .Net FW 3.5 or smaller.

Is there an official stable branch of GtkSharp targeting FW 3.5? What is involved in building a custom version of 2.12 which would target 3.5? I can consider dropping some functionality from the custom version, as I am mostly interested in drawing and text output (pango). Thanks a lot.

Update 08-Nov-2013.

Tried ignoring MS warning and setting SpecificVersion = True, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775538/unable-to-add-rhino-mocks-3-5-to-a-net-2-0-project-in-visual-studio-2010). The project builds, but another project which references this one does not. I get a number of errors on unresolved types, and a few warnings like
`warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyProject.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.` Any idea how the indirect dependency can be tracked down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GtkSharp **is still officially** compatible with the 3.5 version of the .NET framework. (If you go to the sources, you can see that it is compiled with `gmcs`, not `dmcs`.)

My guess is that you're using a distribution which has changed this at the packaging level in order to save disk space (Debian and Ubuntu do this, in order to only ship one set of libraries compiled for the last version of the framework).

Comment: I am confused. I am trying to add a reference to glib-sharp.dll. Its manifest lists metadata version as v1.1.4322; it references mscorlib .ver 1:0:5000:0 and System .ver 1:0:5000:0. These seem to be well within FW 3.5. However, when I add glib-sharp.dll to my project that targets 3.5, MSVC 2010 says: "'gtk-sharp.dll', or one of its dependencies, require a later version of the .NET Framework than the one specified in the project. <...>. Probably a vs2010 issue, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775538/unable-to-add-rhino-mocks-3-5-to-a-net-2-0-project-in-visual-studio-2010)?

Comment: where did you get your gtk-sharp from?

Comment: Installed from [here](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.9/windows-installer/0/mono-2.10.9-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe) via [Mono download page](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html). Referenced dlls from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.9\lib\mono\gac\; chose 2.0 versions for Mono.Cairo and Mono.Posix.

Comment: then I think you've found a bug in the installer

Comment: Same happens with GtkSharp that I built from 2.12 sources on Ubuntu. (built GtkSharp on Ubuntu, issue persists in vs2010 on Win 7)

Comment: The issue was caused by presence of Xamarin Studio's version of GtkSharp on my PC. Even though I was adding references specifically to  "correct", FW 3.5-compatible assemblies, vs2010 was seeing Xamarin Studio's ones, which target 4.0. After deinstallation of GtkSharp/Xamarin, the issue is gone. Thanks for your help knocte!